# How to add if condition in this query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using flask_sqlalchemy.

I have 10 students in 2 classes with fees.

When `school_class_id` is passed I only need to return the students from specific class else all the students.

The first query works fine for listing all students.
In the second code there added `school_class_id` also listing as expected for listing students from a specific class.

But when I add a `school_class_id` filter in `if` condition then it is returning only one student.

This code works fine in fetching all students:

```
result = db.session.query(
                Student, SchoolClass, Guardian,
                func.sum(StudentFee.net_payable).label('total_payable'),
                ).filter(
                    and_(SchoolClass.school_id == user['school_id'],
                    SchoolClass.id == Student.school_class_id),
                    SchoolClass.status == GenEnum.ACTIVE.value).join(
                        StudentGuardian, StudentGuardian.student_id == Student.id).filter(
                            Guardian.id == StudentGuardian.guardian_id
            ).outerjoin(StudentFee,
                StudentFee.student_id == Student.id
                        ).filter(StudentFee.status == NewEnum.ACTIVE.value).group_by(Student.id)

result.all()
```

This code works when passing the `school_class_id`:

```
result = db.session.query(
                Student, SchoolClass, Guardian,
                func.sum(StudentFee.net_payable).label('total_payable'),
                ).filter(
                    and_(SchoolClass.school_id == user['school_id'],
                    # SchoolClass.id == body.get('school_class_id'),
                    SchoolClass.id == Student.school_class_id),
                    SchoolClass.status == GenEnum.ACTIVE.value).join(
                        StudentGuardian, StudentGuardian.student_id == Student.id).filter(
                            Guardian.id == StudentGuardian.guardian_id
            ).outerjoin(StudentFee,
                StudentFee.student_id == Student.id
                        ).filter(StudentFee.status == NewEnum.ACTIVE.value).group_by(Student.id)

result.all()
```

But this code adding filter later has some issue as it's only returning one student:

```
result = db.session.query(
                Student, SchoolClass, Guardian,
                func.sum(StudentFee.net_payable).label('total_payable'),
                )

if body.get('school_class_id'):
    result.filter(SchoolClass.id == body.get('school_class_id'))

result.filter(
        and_(SchoolClass.school_id == user['school_id'],
        SchoolClass.id == Student.school_class_id),
        SchoolClass.status == GenEnum.ACTIVE.value).join(
            StudentGuardian, StudentGuardian.student_id == Student.id).filter(
                Guardian.id == StudentGuardian.guardian_id
).outerjoin(StudentFee,
    StudentFee.student_id == Student.id
            ).filter(StudentFee.status == NewEnum.ACTIVE.value).group_by(Student.id)


result.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy `Query` objects are generative. In other words methods such as `Query.filter()` produce a new object, instead of mutating the existing object. In your attempt to add conditional filtering you produce and discard 2 new queries. The reason why you get only 1 row as a result is that the actual query you end up running has an aggregate without an explicit `GROUP BY` clause, and so the entire set is considered a single group. The fix is simple, just reassign the query when adding filters etc:

```
result = db.session.query(...)

if body.get('school_class_id'):
    result = result.filter(...)

result = result.filter(...).join(...).outerjoin(...).filter(...).group_by(...)

result.all()
```